# Error in reading xls file in R

Tags: r, xls

I am trying to load a "xls" file into R
I have tried using different packages in R like XLConnect,readxl,gdata, but I am unable to read the file properly.

When using XLConnect, I am getting error `NullPointerException (Java)`

You can find the link to a sample xls file [here](http://tps.finra.org/HISTORIC_SPREPORTS-201612.zip)

`s1 <- read_xls("FINRA_IDC_STAR-20110516.xls",
               sheet = 1,skip=1,
               col_names=FALSE,guess_max = min(50,100) ,trim_ws = TRUE)`

Comment: the Commend should be `read.xlsx`

Comment: Not working @PraveenRKaruppannan

Comment: What is the package name that you are using?/

Comment: Try with `read_excel` from `readxl` package

Comment: not working @akrun, I tried using all the packages that I know i.e `XLConnect,readxl,gdata`

Comment: Ok, then your file might be corrupted

Comment: Try to download the file and try on your system once

Comment: Try `XLSX` Package that should fix the issue

Comment: I opened one of your files with Excel (Office 2010 Professional) and clicked on "File" -> "Save". Now I can read your file with `read.xlsx` of the `xlsx` package.

Comment: not working @PraveenRKaruppannan, try downloading the file

Comment: @MarcoSandri can you try reading the file that starts with `FINRA_IDC_STAR`

Comment: Yes, I can read these files, but only after opening and saving with Excel.

Comment: @MarcoSandri I got this error when I tried to load the file `FINRA_IDC_PXTABLES`using `xlsx`package`Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @MarcoSandri I have hundreds of files, I cannot open them all.

Comment: @DurgaGaddam I am able to ready the data in `xlsx'. I'm sure but just a guess its should java error. Try new JDK

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to read your original files using `RODBC`. Try this code:

```
require(RODBC)
conn <- odbcConnectExcel("FINRA_IDC_STAR-20161201.xls")
df <- sqlQuery(conn, "select * from [TradingActivity$]")  
close(conn) 

str(df)

'data.frame':   66 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ F1 : Factor w/ 22 levels "* Indicates trade count is less than 5",..: NA NA NA NA 11 NA 8 NA NA 7 ...
 $ F2 : Factor w/ 4 levels "COUNT","FNMA",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 4 1 NA ...
 $ F3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "SEC ID'S","UNIQUE": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 1 NA ...
 $ F4 : Factor w/ 2 levels "$ TRADES","(000'S)": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 2 NA ...
 $ F5 : Factor w/ 5 levels "*","COUNT","FHLMC",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 5 2 NA ...
 $ F6 : Factor w/ 3 levels "*","SEC ID'S",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 2 NA ...
 $ F7 : Factor w/ 3 levels "$ TRADES","(000'S)",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 2 NA ...
 $ F8 : Factor w/ 3 levels "COUNT","GNMA",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 3 1 NA ...
 $ F9 : Factor w/ 2 levels "SEC ID'S","UNIQUE": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 1 NA ...
 $ F10: Factor w/ 2 levels "$ TRADES","(000'S)": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 2 NA ...
 $ F11: Factor w/ 4 levels "*","COUNT","OTHER AGENCY",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 4 2 NA ...
 $ F12: Factor w/ 3 levels "*","SEC ID'S",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 2 NA ...
 $ F13: Factor w/ 3 levels "$ TRADES","(000'S)",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 2 NA ...
 $ F14: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: Hello Marco, I am getting this error `Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed`when I tried to run this code `odbcConnectExcel2007("FINRA_IDC_STAR-20110701.xls")`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the xls file is your working directory ?